# Save contact for iOS from Google App Engine system

Tags: iphone, ios, google-app-engine, calendar, contacts

We have one system base on Google App Engine and want to create new app. This app help user save contact easily by one click to button on our website. (Like this site http://iphone.mobicontact.info/ --> Browse on iOS and touch to "Download contact to Iphone")

According to http://mobicontact.info/iphone/download-contact-from-web-page/ we must use ics file (Calendar) contain vcf file (Contact) to do our business. By the way, we create a servlet for generate ics file (without vcf file) and it's not working properly. (I think in ics file content was had vcf file. In addition, I can't create file on GAE server, [Does Google App Engine allow creation of files and folders on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693081/does-google-app-engine-allow-creation-of-files-and-folders-on-the-server) ).

Anybody can help me and show me how to create iOS contact file from GAE system? Thank you so much!

Comment: Kindly attach the code "that's not working properly".

Answer (score 0):

You can create any file you want on the "server" you just can't save it back to the local filesystem, you have to use the blobstore or similar. Or you can just send it to the user without saving it at all after creating it on the fly in response to a request.

You can use the [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) or the normal NDB/DB [storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview). For files the size of the ones you mention the latter would be fine I'm sure.

As to why your ics file is not working, I'd say you need to ask another question or update this one with some details of why it "does not work properly" before anyone can help.