# Google App Engine PHP file permissions

Tags: php, google-app-engine

App Engine applications can be implemented using the PHP original runtime now. (see [*Get started with App Engine for PHP - scalable, secure and reliable* on Google Cloud Platform Blog (16 May 2013)](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.de/2013/05/app-engine-adds-php-support.html).

It seems that the PHP process on *Google App Engine* does not have enough permissions to create folders. According to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini), the built-in stream handler `ftp()` [is not supported](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime#Function-Support) too.

Is the GAE file system read-only? What possibilities do we have?

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Does Google App Engine allow creation of files and folders on the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693081/367456) - Please use the search before you ask a question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write to Google Cloud Storage, rather than trying to write to a local file system.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/overview

This can use the regular file functions, here's one of their basic examples.

```
$fp = fopen("gs://my_bucket/some_file.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, "Hello");
fclose($fp);
```