# Appengine app which can deploy static files to itself

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to write a app for appengine which can deploy static files to itself(yes I know i can use blobstore but I don't want to work under its constraints).Do you know is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't save files or folders directly in your application space. But you can save your files in a blob or in Google cloud storage. [Previous post on Stackoverflow discus the same think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693081/does-google-app-engine-allow-creation-of-files-and-folders-on-the-server)

Comment: What if we do it as like as appcfg.py did. There must be a protocol and we can replicate it.

Comment: Can you provide more precise information's about replication of protocol and appcfg.py ? I thing you want to by pass the security but you can't do that.

Comment: appcfg.py has to deploy files with a protocol. I just want to use some protocol and deploy it as it already did. Appengine also has socket library but I guess appcfg deploy files over http, so it could be more easier.

Comment: If you find a solution with appcfg.py please post them. But I think is not possible.