# How to read and write text files from appengine?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, file-handling

I am using eclipse Luna. I want to read and write text files from my appengine and the path of those files I will set on run time from the local host, like "C:\Users\Public\Documents\newfile.txt" . Anyone give me a good code or link or a direction how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to file system in AppEngine but you can use CloudStorage https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage.  Duplicate of [Does Google App Engine allow creation of files and folders on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693081/does-google-app-engine-allow-creation-of-files-and-folders-on-the-server)