# Saving a PHPSpreadSheet Object

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, phpspreadsheet

I have a Laravel application deployed to Google App Engine. Per GAE's architecture rules, you cannot save files to a local path. I am using [PHP Spreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) to generate Xlsx files and download them for the user. So this works locally but not in the deployed app..

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('storage/SomeExcelFile.xlsx');
```

Then I can download the file with..

```
return Storage::disk('public')->download('SomeExcelFile.xlsx');
```

But without being able to saves files locally on the production version of the application, how will I store my file?
I have my application connected to a storage bucket where I can upload files. But I need the file path to do this, and since this file was created scriptually in the application and was never stored prior to deployment, I can't find a way to store it.

As far as I found you can't write the xlsx file directly to a disk. For example I can write a text file with the text `sample data` to my google cloud storage bucket..

```
Storage::disk('gcs')->put('String.txt', 'sample data');
```

But can't find a way to do it with my excel file. Also the application is deployed in the Flex environment so I can't use the file url structure `gs://`

Comment: You don't have any file being saved, like session or logs? Can you open/write files without creating new ones? Maybe you can use an existing file as workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around streaming the file with [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response)

```
$response = new StreamedResponse(
    function () use ($writer) {
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }
);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="Services Reformatted.xlsx"');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
return $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way :

```
file_put_contents(public_path('filename.xlsx'), $writer);
```

Comment: you mean `file_put_contents`? Only works locally doesn't actually write the file correctly, corrupts it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693092) for an explanation as to why this will not work.