# How to deploy Laravel 8 google cloud run with google cloud database

Tags: laravel, docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

Iam looking for help to containerize a laravel application with docker, running it locally and make it deployable to gcloud Run, connected to a gcloud database.
My application is an API, build with laravel, and so far i have just used the docker-compose/sail package, that comes with laravel 8, in the development.

Here is what i want to achieve:

- Laravel app running on gcloud Run.
- Database in gcloud, Mysql, PostgreSQL or SQL server. (prefer Mysql).
- Enviroment stored in gcloud.

My problem is can find any info if or how to use/rewrite the docker-composer file i laravel 8, create a Dockerfile or cloudbuild file, and build it for gcloud.

Maybe i could add something like this in a cloudbuild.yml file:

```
#cloudbuild.yml
  steps:
  # running docker-compose
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.26.2'
    args: ['up', '-d']
```

Any help/guidanceis is appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCWGJV3x1Rs) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah that video, helps alot on how to build some of the conf files and so on. But does not touch on database connection and secrets

Comment: for those you can check both this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) and this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secret-manager-improve-cloud-run-security-without-changing-the-code-634f60c541e6) respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to this question you can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCWGJV3x1Rs) that explains how you can use docker-composer, laravel to deploy an app to Cloud Run with a step-by-step tutorial.

As per database connection to said app, the [Connecting from Cloud Run (fully managed)  to Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) is quite complete on that matter and for secret management I found [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secret-manager-improve-cloud-run-security-without-changing-the-code-634f60c541e6) that explains how to implement secret manager into Cloud Run.

I know this answer is basically just links to the documentation and articles, but I believe all the information you need to implement your app into Cloud Run is in those.

Comment: I successfully deployed my app to Google Cloud App Engine but I'm unable to store files in '/storage'.

Comment: You cannot upload files and store them with Google Cloud App Engine. See details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693081/does-google-app-engine-allow-creation-of-files-and-folders-on-the-server . Store the files on Google cloud storage or equivalent file storage service.